# Mean curvature of a graph

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am trying to verify the equation for the mean curvature of a graph in Euclidean space, but am going wrong somewhere and can't seem to work out where. Here is what I have done so far.

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. If $u:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function, then the graph of $u$ over $\Omega$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ given by $\{(x,u(x))\,|\,x\in\Omega\}$. A unit normal to this hypersurface is
\begin{equation*}
    \nu=(1+\|\nabla u\|^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^1}\partial_1+\dots+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^n}\partial_{n}-\partial_{n+1}\right)
\end{equation*}
and a basis of tangent vectors is given by
\begin{equation*}
    e_i=\partial_i+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^i}\partial_{n+1}.
\end{equation*}
where we denote by $\partial_i$ the coordinate vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. With respect to this frame, up to sign the second fundamental form of the graph should be given by
\begin{align*}
    h_{ij}=\langle\nabla_{e_i}\nu,e_j\rangle&=\langle\nabla_{\partial_i}\nu+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^i}\nabla_{\partial_{n+1}}\nu,\partial_j+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^j}\partial_{n+1}\rangle\\
    &=\langle\nabla_{\partial_i}\nu,\partial_j\rangle+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^j}\langle\nabla_{\partial_i}\nu,\partial_{n+1}\rangle\\
    &=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}((1+\|\nabla u\|^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^j})-\frac{\partial u}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(1+\|\nabla u\|^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
&=(1+\|\nabla u\|^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}
\end{align*}
which would give a mean curvature of $(1+\|\nabla u\|^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\Delta u$, which is not correct. If I didn't have the second term on the third line, I believe I would end up with the desired result, but I can't see why it should vanish. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

(NB: In the above calculation, I wrote that $\nabla_{\partial_{n+1}}\nu=0$ because we can extend $\nu$ smoothly to a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by vertical translation, and clearly the derivative of this extension in the $\partial_{n+1}$-direction is zero. Is this reasoning OK? )

Comment: I wrote some calculations in http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Michigan_1991.pdf

Comment: You need the first fundamental form as well as the second. The mean curvature is the trace of $\text{I}^{-1}\text{II}$, not the trace of $\text{II}$.